# How to filter an object of arrays that have a top level property?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
{
    "1596": [
      {
        "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1596,
        "name": "metropolitan region",
        "iso6393Char3Code": "eng",
      },
      {
        "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1597,
        "name": "région métropolitaine",
        "iso6393Char3Code": "fra",
      }
    ],
    "1597": [
      {
        "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1598,
        "name": "metropolitan department",
        "iso6393Char3Code": "eng",
      },
 {
        "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1599,
        "name": "département métropolitain",
        "iso6393Char3Code": "fra",
      }
    ],
    .....and so on...
}
```

*Note: The above is a shortened example for this question (there are over 100+ items in the array).*

I want to build a drop down menu where users can select an item from the array. I want to only show the english version of these items (`eng`) and so the only items they can select would be like so (ids for each item should be available for the options value).

Required output structure:

```
[
  {
    divisionCategoryID_PK,
    name,
    iso6393Char3Code
  },
  {
   divisionCategoryID_PK,
    name,
    iso6393Char3Code
  },
  ...so on.. 
]
```

I can make the form input, I just need help with creating the options list for the select menu element. How do I create the new array when there is a "top level" property above it (ie, `1596`, etc)? The `1596`, `1597` part is throwing me off. Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Suppose your options take an array of objects of the format: `{ label: 'asdf', value: 123}`, and your raw-data is the object `rawDataObj`, then please try: `Object.values(rawDataObj).filter(data => data.iso6393Char3Code === 'eng').map(data => ({ label: data. name, value: data.divisionCategoryID_PK}))` <--- this should be the options-list you supply to the dropdown.

Comment: that's an object of arrays, not an array of objects

Comment: @mstephen19, correct, i edited the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
    1596: [
        {
            divisionCategoryID_PK: 1596,
            name: 'metropolitan region',
            iso6393Char3Code: 'eng',
        },
        {
            divisionCategoryID_PK: 1597,
            name: 'région métropolitaine',
            iso6393Char3Code: 'fra',
        },
    ],
    1597: [
        {
            divisionCategoryID_PK: 1598,
            name: 'metropolitan department',
            iso6393Char3Code: 'eng',
        },
        {
            divisionCategoryID_PK: 1599,
            name: 'département métropolitain',
            iso6393Char3Code: 'fra',
        },
    ],
};

const format = (obj) => {
    const arr = [];

    for (const ob of Object.values(obj).flat()) {
        if (ob.iso6393Char3Code === 'eng') arr.push(ob);
    }

    return arr;
};

console.log(format(obj));
```

Comment: thank you very much! Let me study and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

**Logic.**

- get all object values
- flat that array.
- filter down the list that only contain `iso6393Char3Code` as `eng`. (You have generated the output Array here).
- Pick out the `name`s in this Array

```js
const data = {
  "1596": [
    {
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1596,
      "name": "metropolitan region",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "eng",
    },
    {
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1597,
      "name": "région métropolitaine",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "fra",
    }
  ],
  "1597": [
    {
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1598,
      "name": "metropolitan department",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "eng",
    },
    {
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1599,
      "name": "département métropolitain",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "fra",
    }
  ],
};

const objects = Object.values(data).flat().filter(item => item.iso6393Char3Code === "eng")
console.log(objects);

const names = objects.map(item => item.name);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that I will need them to be an object so I can have access to the item's id for the options in the menu

Comment: Can you post the required output structure?

Comment: @redshift can you check the updated output?

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me study and get back to you!

Comment: @redshift can you tell me why this answer was not approved, even after posing the best code first?

Comment: The other one was easier to work with in a computed property for VueJS. But, if your answer is better than I can make the change.

Comment: @redshift Both of tha answer doesn't have anything to do with Vue js computer property. Bout both can be implemented as a computed property. But does this needs a long loop for implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
const yearsData = {
  "1596": [{
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1596,
      "name": "metropolitan region",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "eng",
    },
    {
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1597,
      "name": "région métropolitaine",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "fra",
    }
  ],
  "1597": [{
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1598,
      "name": "metropolitan department",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "eng",
    },
    {
      "divisionCategoryID_PK": 1599,
      "name": "département métropolitain",
      "iso6393Char3Code": "fra",
    }
  ]
};

const formattedData = Object.keys(yearsData).reduce((result, year) => {
  result.push(yearsData[year].filter(data => data.iso6393Char3Code === 'eng')[0]);
  
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(formattedData);
```